# Using Python 2.4.3: Want to find the same regex multiple times in a text file

Tags: python, regex

Super NOOB to Python (2.4.3): I am executing a function containing a regular expression which searches through a txt file that I'm importing. I am able to read and run re.search on the text file and the output is correct. I need to fun this for multiple occurrences. The regex occurs 48 times in the text). The code is as follows:

## !/usr/bin/python

import re

dataRead = open('pd_usage_14-04-23.txt', 'r')
dataWrite = open('test_write.txt', 'w')

text = (dataRead.read()) #reads and initializes text for conversion to string
s = str(text) #converts text to string for reading

def user(str):

```
    re1='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))' # Word 1
    re2='(\\s+)'    # White Space 1
    re3='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))' # Word 2
    re4='(\\s+)'    # White Space 2
    re5='((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))'  # Alphanum 1

    rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    #alphanum1=rg.group(5)
    re.findall(rg, s, flags=0)
    #print "("+alphanum1+")"+"\n"

    #if m:
        #word1=m.group(1)
        #ws1=m.group(2)
        #word2=m.group(3)
        #ws2=m.group(4)
        #alphanum1=m.group(5)
        #print "("+alphanum1+")"+"\n"

    return
```

user(s)

dataRead.close()
dataWrite.close()

OUTPUT: g706454

THIS OUTPUT IS CORRECT! BUT...!
I need to run it multiple times reading text thats further down.

I have 2 other definitions that need to be ran multiple times also. I need all 3 to run consecutively, and then run again but starting with the next line or something to search and output newer data. All the logic I tried implement returns the same output.

So I have something like this:
for count in range (0,47):
        if stop_read:
                date(s)
                usage(s)
                user(s)

stop_read is a definition that finds the next line after the data that I'm looking for (date, usage, user). I figured I could call this to say If you hit stop_read, read the next line and run definitions all over again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use raw strings for regexes to avoid double backslash escapes `r''`.

Comment: Python 2.4 is ten years old and out if support. Do you really need to do development on a legacy platform? Consider Python 3 for new projects, or at least 2.6.

Comment: Also if you are new to Python you should read [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to learn how to format your code better.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've edited the post to show that I am using raw strings for this. Thanks again! re.findall isn't working quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do for a regex in Python 3, should be similar to Python 2. This is for a multiline searc.

```
regex = re.compile("\\w+-\\d+\\b", re.MULTILINE)
```

Then later on in code I have something like:

```
myset.update([m.group(0) for m in regex.finditer(logmsg.text)])
```

Maybe you might want to update your Python if you can, 2.4 is old, old, and stale.

Answer (score 0):

looks like `re.findall` would solve your problem:

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

    If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
    list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
    has more than one group.

    Empty matches are included in the result.
```

Comment: I need a more structured output than just a list. I need each function to exe. and find their respective regex's in order. Is there a controlled findall?